# Jasypt out of maintenance? What to use for encryption with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, jasypt

Jasypt (https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt) and the according Spring Boot integration (https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) do not really seem to be alive any longer.

- issues with the latest LTS Java version (17)
- no activity in the most recent history

What are current good practices for encrypting properties in Spring Boot applications using open source libraries? Simple solutions preferred.

Comment: Because the encryption is a two-way encryption this is inherently unsafe (more or less). So instead of storing encrypted values in a properties file, more and more people/orgs start to use vaults (like the HashiCorp vault for instance) to store secrets. Or provide them on runtime as environment/container variables.

Comment: check [Spring Cloud Config Server - Encryption and Decryption](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_encryption_and_decryption)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Java 17 issues - if you mean java modules I think the whole spring project is not compatible. The fact they don't need to make changes is not bad ... whats the problem with Jasypt really? I'm not familiar with Spring Cloud. You make it sound like its a Spring Boot replacement but that does not seem to be the case right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Cloud has builtin support for decrypting properties. Any property that starts with `{cipher}...` will automatically be decrypted at runtime. Similar to jasypt, a 'master' encryption key is used. Configuring this key can be done  by specifying `encrypt.key` in bootstrap.yaml or by specifying the `ENCRYPT_KEY` environment variable. Default uses symmetric encryption, but it's also possible to use asymmetric keys.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: {cipher}xxxxx
```

The Spring CLI also has support for encrypting values:

```
spring encrypt --key MySeCrEtMaStErKeY 'secretAPIkey'
```

Then start your app by specifying the master encryption key in bootstrap.yaml or using an environment variable:

```
ENCRYPT_KEY=MySeCrEtMaStErKeY java -jar myapp.jar
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#encryption-and-decryption

For more sophisticated setups, I highly recommend using Hashicorp Vault. It's open source and free to use.

Comment: I dont understand how is it secure to encrypt all passwords in your application.properties file but provide encryption key for these password in that very same file as well (or in bootstrap.properties file)?  All someone needs is to open that file, take encryption key and use it to decrypt the passwords.  Mind explaining, I feel I am missing something.  Thanks and much appreciated

Comment: The master encryption key should not be provided in the same file, usually you provide that via environment variables, or by passing the master encryption key in 'bootstrap.yaml', whereas all normal properties are stored in 'application.yaml'. 
To be honest, I think nowadays people should use AWS KMS or Hashicorp Vault, instead of relying on a single master key.

Comment: Does Spring Cloud have any restrictions regarding the use outside of major cloud environments like Azure, AWS, Google Cloud,...?

Answer (score 0):

blagerweij's answer is correct. I tried to follow his suggestion but I ran into an issue with the new version of the Spring Boot CLI and I'm trying to explain how I solved my issue. I'm just sharing my findings in case it helps anyone.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7 for my project and I was trying to find a way to encrypt some sensitive data in the application.properties file. I did some research and found a couple of options.

a. Use the Jasypt library for encryption & decryption.

b. Use a key vault like Hashicorp or AWS Secrets manager

c. Write my own encryption and decryption function in Spring Boot. Run the sensitive data(e.g. database password) thru the encryption function and store the encrypted value in the application.properties file. Use the decryption function where required to decrypt the value.

Cons of each approach

a - Jasypt library is out of maintenance since end of 2022. This can be deduced from the maven repository.

b - AWS Secrets manager costs money. I'm helping an NGO on this project and we are trying to minimize cost  without compromising on security. I did not research  Hashicorp since my application is hosted on AWS.

c - Spring Boot uses autoconfiguration to configure the data source. So the decryption of the DB password stored in application.properties needs to happen during the autoconfiguration. Something similar needs to happen to decrypt the Oauth2 keys.
I couldn't figure out a way to override the autoconfiguration and decrypt the sensitive data in the override.

I landed on this page after a lot of research and am very grateful to blagerweij for his post. He suggested using the Spring CLI to generate the encrypted password and Spring cloud library to do the decryption.
So I tried it out. If you include the Spring cloud starter library in your dependencies, it automatically takes care of the decryption. I tried using the Spring Boot CLI to generate the encrypted password but the encrypt/decrypt options don't work with the new version of the CLI. Please refer to this link for more details -
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli/issues/180

If you refer to the link above, there are a couple of suggestions to generate the encrypted password and one of them is the spring-crypto-cli.
I used the spring-crypto-cli as mentioned in the link below to generate the encrypted password
https://github.com/mptechnology/spring-crypto-cli

I then used this encrypted password in my application.properties file as follows. As shown, you need to prefix the encrypted value with {cipher}. This tells Spring that the value is encrypted and needs to be decrypted.
spring.datasource.password={cipher}f480c675

I mentioned above that we need to use the spring-cloud-starter library in our project for decryption to happen automatically. The below link gives you the compatibility matrix between Spring Boot and the Spring cloud library. Since I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0, I had to use the 2021.0.x version of the Spring cloud starter library and that is where this link helped me.
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud/

Comment: Can this answer be worded so it can stand on its own? It's ok to use references to sources for the info, but the relevant bits should be in your answer. As it is, it's little more than "[click here] for the real answer"

Comment: Jaredo, Blagerweij has provided the correct answer, but things have changed with the Spring CLI since May 2022. Hence the answer didn't work for me as described and I explained what needs to be done to get it to work. In any case, I will update my answer to the best of my ability and try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This dependency supported on LTS spring boot with java17.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Run this Maven command to generate encrypted password.

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password="the password" -Djasypt.plugin.value="theValueYouWantToEncrypt"
```